# crm2011 How to tell a system entity is customized or not

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Just as the title, how to tell a system entity in crm 2011 is customized or not? 
Definitely, it can be done by comparing its metadata with the same system entity from another clean Organization.

I want to know whether the following approaches exist:
1. Is there any flag or indicator on built-in crm UI?
2. any web service API?
3. any approach via CRM_DB?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a flag in the UI however look at the Fields for an entity you'll notice any custom attributes will have a prefix including an underscore (If its not part of a solution it will be "new_").

Also you can always view the "ExtensionBase" tables (for example AccountExtensionBase) as this stores all custom attributes

Comment: I concur with looking at the ExtensionBase tables. Future readers be warned, they are gone in CRM 2015.

Comment: ExtensionBase tables also do not exist in 2013.